# Collection.sort by Date doesn't work on all Devices

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to sort some arrays in ASC order using Dates using Collection.sort; But when I make some test on several devices it only worked properly in a Tablet and doesn't work on cellphones. The Tablet Android version is 8.1 and the cellphones version, one is 5.0.1 and the other 9.0.

collection.sort() works fine in every device when I compare the dates AS Strings, but it doesn't rearranges the way I need for example: I need a list of clients in Asc order like: 30/08/2019 , 31/08/2019 , 02/09/2019 but comparing the String does this: 02/09/2019, 30/08/2019, 31/08/2019. I hope my explanation it's understandable

//The clientsParent model has several arrays within witch i need to sort

```
  ClientModel client = new ClientModel();
  client.setFechaGestion(Utilities.convertStringToDate("02/09/2019 02:20:00 PM"));

  clientsParent.get(parentIndex).getClients().add(client);

  Collections.sort(clientsParent.get(parentIndex).getClients(), (c1, c2) -> 
  c1.getFechaGestion().compareTo(c2.getFechaGestion()));



adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is the method from my Utilities class where I convert the strings given by the JSON from the web service for a more precise sort.

```
  public static Date convertStringToDate(String date){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
        Date convertedDate = new Date();
        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertedDate;
    }
```

**EDIT**

By reading the comments and researching this was indeed a *Regional Setting* issue, if you have this kind of issue in your project the only thing you have to do is add a Locale as a second parameter, If you don't find a locale in the default list you can instantiate one using its constructor for example:

```
  Locale localSpanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa", localSpanish);
        Date convertedDate = new Date();
        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertedDate;
```

**P.D.**: As answered in this post try not using Date and SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Could you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please? With sample input, expected result and observed result. Even if it is only reproducible on those devices. Your code looks correct at first sight.

Comment: `'02/09/2019 02:20 PM'` is not a `String` (single quotes) and even if it was, it does not follow the date format due to `:ss` part missing.

Comment: Sure, I edited the post with a quick example. I forgot to mention that the collection.sort() works fine in every device when I compare the dates AS Strings, but  it doesn't rearranges the way I need  for example:  I need a list of clients in Asc order like: *30/08/2019 , 31/08/2019 , 02/09/2019* but comparing the String does this:  *02/09/2019, 30/08/2019, 31/08/2019*. I hope my explanation it's understandable

Comment: What's the return type of `getFechaGestion()`? Your observed behavior does indeed look like you're sorting by String and not by Date. Device differences could be explained by different regional settings and date formats.

Comment: it's a Date the value that `getFechaGestion()` returns. Oh, yes, maybe could be the regional settings of each device

Comment: To fix regional settings issue, force use of English, so it'll always be `AM` / `PM` by adding `Locale` as second parameter: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.US)`

Comment: You are adding 1 (one) item to the clients of the client parent, sorting it and claiming that the sorting is incorrect on one device? I repeat, please give sample input, expected result and observed wrong result for us all to see, or we don’t stand a chance. I downvoted because you haven’t provided what can count as a minimal, reproducible example (follow the link from my first comment). And please put all relevant information in the question itsellf, not into comments, so we have everything in one place.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments!. By reading you all and reasearching I solved it. As **laalto** said it was a regional setting problem and following **Andreas** answer I forced the DateFormat to use an instatiated Locale (in my case) Spanish lenguage like  `Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES")`. I really apologize if I didn't complement the issue with more details (I'm kinda new in the community). Thank you all again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Never use `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`
- [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is the class for you, given your input of date and time-of-day but no time zone or offset-from-UTC
- Implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface on your class, or pass a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)).
- To implement `compareTo` method on your class, simply ask the `LocalDateTime` objects to compare themselves, as that class implements `compareTo`. 
  `this.when.compareTo( that.when )`

## ISO 8601

> "02/09/2019 02:20:00 PM"

When exchanging date-time values as text, always use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Use [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) rather than AM/PM.

Ex: `2019-09-02T14:20:00"

> I convert the strings given by the JSON from the web service

Educate the publisher of that web service on the benefits of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using *terrible* date-time classes. These were supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310 that defines the modern *java.time* classes.

Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `Date`.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

> collection.sort() works fine in every device when I compare the dates AS Strings

No, do not store date-time values as text. We have classes for this.

## `LocalDateTime`

Define a formatting pattern to match the input string, since you are not using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

Notice how we pass a `Locale` to specify the human language and cultural norms to be used in translating the `AM`/`PM`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu hh:mm:ss a" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
```

Parse strings.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.format( input , f ) ;
```

Use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as the type of your class member field, not `String`. The `LocalDateTime` objects know how to sort, having implemented [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Be aware that **`LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment**. Lacking the context of time zone or offset, it stores only a date and a time-of-day. If you are trying to track specific points on the timeline, you should be using `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`. Use `LocalDateTime` only for booking future appointments when we want to maintain a specific time-of-day regardless of politicians changing the offset used in that region.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

## Example app

Simple example. Not necessarily robust enough for production use.

Define the class holding the `LocalDateTime` object.

```
class Event implements Comparable< Event > {
    // Member field variable.
    public LocalDateTime when ;

    // Constructor
    public Event( LocalDateTime localDateTime ) {
        this.when = localDateTime ;
    }

    // Implements `Comparable` interface.
    @Override
    public int compareTo( Event that ) {
        return this.when.compareTo( that.when ) ;
    }

    // Override `Object.toString` for better reporting of the value of this object.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.when.toString() ;
    }
}
```

And example usage in a `main` method.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.time.* ;
import java.time.format.* ;
import java.time.temporal.* ;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List< Event > events = new ArrayList<>( 3 ) ;
        events.add( new Event( LocalDateTime.of( 2019 , 3 , 14 , 12 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ) ) ;
        events.add( new Event( LocalDateTime.of( 2019 , 1 , 17 , 14 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ) ) ;
        events.add( new Event( LocalDateTime.of( 2019 , 2 , 21 , 17 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ) ) ;
        System.out.println("Before: " + events ) ;

        Collections.sort( events ) ;
        System.out.println("After: " + events ) ;
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WBrhKO).

> Before: [2019-03-14T12:00, 2019-01-17T14:00, 2019-02-21T17:00]
>
> After: [2019-01-17T14:00, 2019-02-21T17:00, 2019-03-14T12:00]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really good one. I'll have this in consideration in the future. You are right SimpleDateFormat and Date werent the answer. Regards!